# What is /oldroot/ and why do I get umount failed on shutdown?

Tags: partitioning, mount, shutdown

I get an umount failed for oldroot on shutdown error.

I have used several disk tool mount/gpart/fdisk/df etc to search for the /oldroot and I believe it is never mounted and does not exist.

However, when I shutdown I get umount failed error for this disk. The error is not causing a problem and I read on the web that it is normal.

1. What is oldroot and why does Ubuntu think it is mounted?
2. Is this real failure or a "normal" shutdown error?
3. I don't always get this error but cannot determine why it will shutdown sometimes without errors.  Any ideas?

Finally, question 1 is the most important question to me and I cannot find the answer on the internet.

Configuration  18.10, encrypted disk, nothing special, just barebone laptop.